# IIS7 failover cluster across datacenters

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, cluster, failover, datacenter

I have servers in two different datacenters with each datacenter getting static IPs.  What I would like to do is setup the servers as IIS7 servers and allowing them to failover from datacenter to datacenter with little (or preferably) no interruption.  Servers on both sides are running Windows Server 2008 x64 with IIS7 (or 7.5 if needed).  I am interested in how to point DNS traffic to the new datacenter without manual human intervention.

For example:

- Datacenter A:

  - IP: 192.168.1.115
  - Servers: Server 2008 x64 w/ IIS 7

- Datacenter B:

  - IP: 192.168.1.220
  - Servers: Server 2008 x64 w/ IIS 7

- Other information:

  - Domain Name: Example.org
  - Domain DNS: 192.168.1.115

If Datacenter A connectivity went down (broken service line, etc.) how does the traffic know to route to Datacenter B on 192.168.1.220?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideal setup would probably use something like an F5 Networks Global Traffic Manager (http://www.f5.com/products/big-ip/global-traffic-manager.html).  A hardware appliance running the GTM software would sit at each data center.  There is much more information on the F5 site as to how this works but is exactly the setup you describe and is fully automated.

Another option would be to look at a cloud based solution (Rackspace and Amazon are a couple of examples).  They have solutions that would mostly guarantee your up-time requirements.